# Nameclash when importing packages that has the word 'django' in the name?

Tags: python, django, import, package, name-clash

I have a somewhat odd problem. I decided to rename an entire branch of my package from

```
foo.bar.somemodule
```

to

```
foo.django.bar.somemodule
```

The problem is after this is done, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/eclipse/foo/src/foo/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named core.management
```

If I now, revert the name to

```
foo.djangox.bar.somemodule
```

IT WORKS! Notice, the 'x' I added to the word django.

It seems there are some kind of name clash when using foo.django.bar.somemodule, but What gives? They should be separate from django itself.

All the imports in my code are of the form

```
from foo.django.bar.somemodule import someobject
import foo.django.bar.somemodule
```

edit: to clarify there is an 'x' in the second to last import

Comment: According to the traceback, it's not from foo.django.bar.somemodule import someobject, it's from django.core.management import execute_manager.  So the foo at the beginning is apparently not there in manage.py. Am I reading your traceback incorrectly?

Comment: My guess that the directory of `foo` is in your python path. If it can not find `django` somewhere else first it will try to import in from there and since you used the same name.....

Comment: @Jacinda S: I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but to clarify, manage.py is part of django and automatically generated. I never put foo.django.bar.somemodule within installed apps, so it automatically looks through the entire source directory within and complains. I intended to integrate the code, but attempted to isolate the problem.

Comment: Looking at it again, I agree with Torsten as the most likely explanation.  In manage.py, above line 2, put the following to debug: import sys; print sys.path

Comment: Another easy check that would tell you the same thing would be       from django import bar

Comment: Yes, you can try something like `import django` in a python interactive shell and then check `os.path.dirname(django.__file__)` (`import os` first) to actually see where the module is imported from. If it is your `foo.django` module it is definitely your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: On my opinion You haven't to give your modules name of system modules(django, os, sys and other)

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a situation where you want to perform an [absolute import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), but your Python version doesn't do them by default. Add `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the afflicted file to tell the Python VM to activate it.